# why my assembly code make an error message on visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86-16

I received an error message like:
"1>hn.asm(15): error A2006: undefined symbol : DGROUP"
my code is:

```
page 60,132
title a05 exe move and add operation

.model small
.stack 64


.data
fldd dw 215
flde dw 125
fldf dw ?

.code
main proc far
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov ax,fldd
add ax,flde
mov fldf,ax

mov ax,4c00h
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

this is a program which works on visual Masm but doesn't work in visual studio.

Comment: Does your version of Visual Studio support 16 bit builds and does it include 16 bit libraries?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2019. my processor is 32 bit i386- I don't know about 16 bit libraries. I am starter in assembly. I previously was using Gui Turbo assembler. That works good.

Comment: `main proc far` doesn't make sense in assembly for a 32-bit executable, neither does `mov ax,@data` / `mov ds,ax`.  There probably isn't a CRT version that can call your main as a far call, only a normal near call, and you shouldn't mess up the `ds` segment selector set up by the kernel.  (Obviously this is intended to be built as 16-bit code, but if you aren't doing that then most of your code needs to be thrown out, except for the actual mov/add/mov part)

Comment: You need a 16 bit tool set. Looks like you have one with Visual Masm, which I was unaware of. I use Visual C / C++ 1.52 and Masm 6.11 for 16 bit builds (includes a text type IDE called Programmers Workbench), but these can only be run on 32 bit versions of Windows or on 16 bit MSDOS if you have it. Win 7 has virtual PC which can be used for XP or MSDOS, but Win 10 requires some downloaded tool like Virtual Box.

Comment: where can I find legal instructions for Nasm and visual studio related to assembly language programming?